# Asynchronous file and folder copy - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, file-io, copy

I have a method to copy all files and folders in one directory to another, and it works recursively. My problem is that it blocks the main thread and I would like to make the actual copying of files and folders asynchronous.  I currently am using a function to copy files over asynchronously, but it does not seem to work.
Here is the code:

```
private async void copyEverything(string source, string target)
    {
        // Variable to hold the attributes of a file
        FileAttributes attributes;

        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " + source);
        }

        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(target))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
        }

        // Loop through for all files in a directory
        foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(source))
        {
            if (!File.Exists(targetFolder + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                attributes = File.GetAttributes(filename);

                if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
                {
                    //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("File {" + filename + "} is READ ONLY");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(target + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
                            {
                                await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                                filesRemaining--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Loop through each subdirectory in the current directory and recursively call the
        // copyEverything() method using the subdirectory's full name and the name of the
        // target folder plus the subdirectory folder name
        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            foldersRemaining--;
            string temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(target, subdir.Name);
            copyEverything(subdir.FullName, temppath);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work without blocking the main thread?

Comment: Side note, you can improve performance a lot by having `EnumerateDirectories` and `EnumerateFiles` use the search option to search recursively, rather than making the method recursive.  Recursion is much more expensive for an async method than for a traditional method.  Since you don't appear need to use the UI context in the method at all you can also add `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the task you await.

Comment: For every recursive file/folder copy there will be a file system that will overflow your stack.

Comment: I'd be tempted to fork off another process to run `robocopy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still doing a bunch of `IO` on the main thread: `Directory.Exist`, `File.Exist`, etc...  You probably want to avoid doing the entire thing on the main thread.

So, an easy solution would be to add a new method:

```
private void copyEverythingAsync(string source, string target)
{
  Task.Run(()=> copyEverything(source, target));
}
```

And then remove the `async/await` from the `copyEverything` method.

This will move the operation onto a new thread from the `ThreadPool` and not block your main thread.

Comment: But he's awaiting the long running operation, so it should be properly asynchronous already.  This is just hiding the problem, whatever it is, rather than fixing it.

Comment: @Servy But, his problem is that he wants to not block the main thread.

Comment: you should return the `Task` to add `async/await` support.

Comment: @JustinPihony Which he won't be doing if the method is properly asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy - I think part of the problem is him using the `IO` he is still doing on the main thread.  With a deep enough directory structure, this could be a long operation.

Comment: @Andrew But it's still not CPU bound work, it's IO work, as you said, and so should simply be made asynchronous, rather than offloaded to a thread pool thread.

Comment: @Andrew - I tested what I currently have with a folder that is 1.4 GBs in size. There are only a couple folders but inside of it but it stops pretty much everything until it is done.  I am testing your answer right now.

Comment: @RXC If you don't have a particularly large and complex folder higherarchy, but just have a reasonably small number of rather large files, then the code should be fine as is.  Odds are there is a problem with some code you haven't shown.

Comment: @Servy The question is asking how to avoid blocking the main thread... I agree that he is experiencing an IO problem and not a workflow problem.

Comment: @Andrew And your suggesting offloading IO bound work to a thread pool thread, which is not appropriate for an asynchronous program.  It's hiding the problem without fixing it, which is harmful.

Comment: The code you provided works. I will continue to figure out why my original code didn't work though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply marking a method `async` does not make it `async`, you need to `await` the non-UI/blocking code. The `await` is where your asynchronous code should go, often in a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

All code that is not in an `await` will run in the context of the calling thread (the main in your case). So, even though you are `await`ing the copy, you should probably just `await` the entire block, using a `Task` as already specified

Comment: His code is awaiting.  Maybe not as much as it should, but the one most important operation is awaited.

Comment: Oops...missed that....I still think he is blocking more than he should, though...I will edit my answer

Comment: I do have an await statement used with the CopyToAsync method. Is there something more I have to do?